# Would native speakers say WHILE in this context

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

A sentence:

> He listens to music **while** practicing handwriting.

**While** sounds okay here.

But, in this sentence:

> He is listening to music **while** practicing handwriting.
>   (Present continuous tense)

Here **while** doesn't sound perfect to me ( a besic learner ).

What would **native speakers** use?

**and / at the same time as / simultaneously or something else**

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The most ordinary phrase would be

**He is listening to music and practicing handwriting**

If you want to emphasise that it is simultaneous

**He is cooking and doing his homework *at the same time***

But you can certainly use _simultaneously__ and *at the same time as*.